# Bootstrap tooltip and datatable not working same page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatable, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have datatable plugin on page which is downloaded from `datatables.net` And I initialize if it needed. But `data-toggle="tooltip"` stops working after initialize. I was tried `JQ 1.12.3` and `1.11.3`, same result. I'm sorry for asking this silly question but I'm stuck on that for days.

This is error on tooltip : `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function`

So here is sample code.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Sample text">Click here</a>

<table class="table datatable">
<tr>
  <td>Value1</td>
  <td>Value2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Value1</td>
  <td>Value2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Only one data-toggle attribute is allowed per element.

Comment: Yeah I know. Ok edited my question.

Comment: make a fiddle so that we can help you, try to replace $ by jQuery perhaps it works